# Python list of mutable objects without duplicates

Tags: python, types, cpython

I created a Python class with some string/number attributes and a list attribute. Now I need a list of some objects of this class without duplicates. The objects can have the same values (are equal), but no object should be present more than one time.

I know that sets only support immutable objects, but the values of my objects will change.

Is there another suitable data type for this problem? Technically speaking, I need an array of object references without duplicates that implements all collection-class methods.

Comment: Conceptually, this doesn’t make a great deal of sense—if you change one of your mutable objects, you might change it to become identical to something else in the list. If you’re doing a one-time filtering, you might consider a “wringer” approach, converting everything to a immutable type, using `set()` and then converting back to a mutable type.

Comment: I don't really care about equality. The objects represent an object in the real world. The objects could be of a class "person" with only a height attribute. There can be more than one person with the same height in the list, but every person can only be there once.

Comment: As the answers to the linked question suggest, set works out of the box with custom classes, because the default __hash__ function returns a value based on object identity which does not change if object values change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set()` works exactly as you hope. Just use it directly:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, height):
        self.height = height

Tom = Person(190)
George = Person(200)
Bob = Person(200)

friends = set([Tom, George, Bob])
assert len(friends) == 3
```

Comment: I wonder why they made list "unhashable" while it could work the same way as with custom classes. I guess this solution will not work if Person is derived from list.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a for loop such as this:

```
unique = []
for item in yourList:
    if not item in unique:
        unique.append(item)
```

But as for the built in types, sets and dicts cannot hash these classes as you just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a mutable class with an equality operator that checks some of its mutable attributes to determine if two instances are equal. You want to build a list of these instances, excluding only repeated references to the same instance, not equal-valued instances.

You can do this by keeping a `set` of the `id`s of the values you've included so far:

```
# given some pre-existing list of objects, initial_list

seen_ids = set()
deduped_list = []
for instance in initial_list:
    if id(instance) not in seen_ids:
        deduped_list.append(instance)
        seen_ids.add(id(instance))
```

You can instead use a dictionary and a generator expression if you wanted to do it all on one expression:

```
deduped_list = list(dict((id(instance), instance) for instance in initial_list).values())
```

The `list` call is only necessary if you're using Python 3 and need an actual list object. If you just need something iterable, the return value from `values` will work just fine as it is. If you need the values to be in the same order they first appeared in the original list, you can use an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: I guess this is a solution, but managing the memory addresses (return value of id()) with python does not seem like a very performant way.